# Bokeh logarithmic scale for Bar chart

Tags: python, charts, visualization, bokeh

I know that I can do logarithmic scales with bokeh using the plotting API:

```
p = figure(
    tools="pan,box_zoom,reset,previewsave",
    y_axis_type="log", y_range=[0.001, 10**22], title="log axis example",
    x_axis_label='sections', y_axis_label='particles'
)
```

However, I can't figure out how to get this to apply to high level charts such as `Bokeh.charts.Bar.` In general I'm having a lot of trouble grokking what to relationship is between a `Chart` and a `figure`. Can anyone point me to some documentation on this or explain how to modify things which are only exposed through figure and have them affect my Chart.

Answer (score 3):

I am specifically going to update the documentation describing the different Bokeh APIs this week, but for now, the three Bokeh APIs in increasing order of "level":

- *models* interface: lowest level API, base serialization layer, must put everything together everything manually
- *glyphs* interface (bokeh.plotting): mid-level API, easily create plots/figures centered around visual glyphs with attributes tied to data
- *charts* interface (bokeh.charts): high level API for canned/schematic statistical charts, e.g. "BoxPlot" and "Histogram".

There is no particular relation between `figure` and the various chart functions, except that they both produces subclasses of `Plot` as output.

I am not sure it is currently possible to add a log axis to the Bar plot in "charts" interface (that would be a reasonable feature to add). However it would be simple to make a boxplot "by hand" using the middle "glyphs" interface using `rect` or `quad` glyphs. Here is a quick example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("bars.html")

p = figure(title="log bar example", y_axis_type="log")

p.quad(
    bottom=0, top=[10**5, 10**8, 10**3], 
    left=[0, 2, 4], right=[1,3,5]
)

show(p)
```

Comment: How can I plot your code with this parameters: `left=[0, 4, 2], right=[1,5,3]`? So I want the x_axis not to be sorted. And in your code I want the highest value (`10**8`) to be the last. Thank you!!

Comment: You can provide the values in any order you like. You have written the answer in your question.

Comment: OK, you are right! (I was not enough clear...) My problem is that I have (numerical) ID-s at x-axis and I want a sorted Bar chart, so let say `my_value=15` at `ID=0`, `my_value=10` at `ID=2` and `my_value=5` at `ID=1`. So I want the x-axis look like this: `0-2-1` and y-axis look like this: `15-10-5`. Is it possible?

Comment: So at `Bar`, the second parameter is `list of strings` so the values of x-axis are not sorted by bokeh. (I can sort my dataframe if I want to sort it.). But at `quad` the `left` & `right` parameters are list of floats, so they are automatically sorted. How can I specify not to sort these values, so let bokeh display my values in the order as I specify the values. Or how can I specify categorical x-axis type? Thank you!

Comment: Please see https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7369
I believe I have found a bug introduced in bokeh 0.12 whereby your answer to this question is no longer working (no bars are displayed).

Comment: Currently you must avoid data coordinates with zero on log axes. Setting a very small value e.g `bottom=1e-10` is a workaround for now.