# Bokeh Library in python : can I provide a custom y range in terms of values to have?

Tags: python, bar-chart, data-visualization, bokeh

The data I have is skewed. I plotting vertical bars wherein most of the bars height is around say 2000-10000 units but couple of bars are as huge as 10000000 units. As a result of which only couple of bars are visible , the short ones are not visisble because y_range(start_value,end_value).

Can I provide custom y-range as 0,1000,2000,3000,7000,10000,100000,1000000 ...something of this sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking the y axis can often be misleading, and is not currently an option in Bokeh (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785310/having-broken-y-axis-in-bokeh-plot-figure?rq=1)). I would instead recommend plotting the y axis on a log scale, which will allow the smaller values to be seen more easily. In your call to `figure()` add the option `y_axis_type="log"`.

Comment: No problem! See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006981/bokeh-logarithmic-scale-for-bar-chart) for more info on log scales in Bokeh bar charts.